# php exec() error...Anyone know what this means?

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu

I have just installed ffmpeg on ubuntu using this guide http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=786095, when I execute the ffmpeg command shown below, it **works fine in terminal** and it works when I execute the php file I am using **through the terminal** by using the 'php' command.

When I try to execute the file using a browser, however, I get the following error in my apache error log. If anyone could give me guidance, I would really appreciate it.

**ERROR**

> /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg:
>   /opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1: version
>   `GCC_4.2.0' not found (required by
>   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6)

**PHP code**

> define('FFMPEG_LIBRARY',
>   '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg');
>
> $command =
>   shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i
>   /home/geoff/Desktop/cave.wmv -acodec
>   libfaac -aq 100 -vcodec libx264
>   -preset slow -crf 22 -threads 0 /home/geoff/Desktop/newvideo.flv');

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me.

http://blog.codyjung.com/2011/05/29/problems-with-lampp-and-exec/

I went into /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2

and copied the libgcc_s.so into

/opt/lampp/lib and renamed it to libgcc_s.so.1 to overwrite the previous file

Comment: This helped me too, quick and dirty. Of course not using /opt/lampp would be better, but why change a (otherwise) running system?

Comment: This is helped me too... +1 for you.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you've got some dependency version issues. I'm guessing you copied the libraries from some other server which was using a different version of the core system files than this one does.

Your best bet is to build from source on the machine you're using it from. That will ensure that your libraries aren't linking to something that isn't present on your system.

**EDIT**
And actually, the reference to /opt/lampp makes me think that you're not using the standard webserver install that you normally would on an Ubuntu server, but are instead using lampp. That could be the source of your conflict -- if the lampp stuff is linked differently than the "normal" system libraries, then you might not be able to use them together.

Comment: Are you talking about FFMPEG libraries? I just followed the guide. Is it because I used git clone? So you are saying I should uninstall and use the synaptic file manager to search these libraries? What if I was using CentOS instead of Ubuntu? How would I get these libraries then? apt-get?

Comment: What is the standard webserver install? On my home machine I use it for testing so I use lampp? Is there a different way?

Answer (score 0):

The user your web server is running under does not have the same environment as your terminal user.  You will need to add /opt/lampp/lib to the web server user's environment.  Look for /opt/lampp/lib in /etc/ld.so.conf and the files in /etc/ld.so.conf.d.  If it's not there, make a new file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d with a line containing just that path.  You will need to restart the web server.

Comment: Does it matter what the file is called?

Comment: I created a file called addir.conf in /etc/ld.so.conf.d with the line /opt/lampp/lib and restarted server, and I still get same error in my log.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this post: http://fedoraforum.org/forum/showpost.php?p=1375187&postcount=2

I feel your problem could be solved, try installing PHP from APT-GET instead of LAMPP and see does it solve your problem.

You can get PHP,APACHE & MySQL by:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2, libapache2-mod-php5, php5, mysql-client, mysql-common, mysql-server
- http://rakeshsankar.wordpress.com/2010/09/10/install-setup-debian-server/
```

Comment: It is not possible to just copy and paste the missing file? I only use lampp for its ease of use and phpmyadmin. How would I administer my server and mysql database if I only install the packages?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance. How is installing the entire lamp stack going to solve a dependency issue with ffmpeg?

Comment: Sometimes, the LAMP stack version compiled from LAMPP source would have used old libraries to compile (PHP,MySQL,etc). These dependencies can be resolved if it is installed directly. I see @Scarface resolved it by copying GCC files - and the same would have happened when LAMP stack is installed separately.